# Run selenium webdriver on localhost:8080

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to run my test scenarios on localhost as the following URL.

```
localhost:8080
```

Can anybody help me to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the scenario more in detail like what problem you are facing or what exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: i tried to open localhost:8080 in firefox browser url using selenuim

Comment: Are you hosting your application on this URL ?

Answer (score 2):

this should work assuming 8080 is the right port...

(the the default is usually localhost:4444)

mind that the need the appropriate capabilities.

```
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/wd/hub"), capability);
```

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is a by default address of our system. It can work as a domain name also. And you can replace "localhost" to "127.0.0.1".

```
So, on behalf of website url you can use URL: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/" in your project.
```